# Only Author+Title+Year in footnote

Tags: biblatex

I am using

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=verbose-inote,]{biblatex}
```

Is it possible to have only Author+Title+Year in the footnote, but the full reference in `\printbibliography`?

Answer (score 17):

This can be done by using the `authortitle` citation style

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=verbose-inote,citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
```

and by patching (using the `xpatch` package, i.e., `\usepackage{xpatch}`) the `cite` bibmacro; namely:

```
\xapptobibmacro{cite}{\setunit{\nametitledelim}\printfield{year}}{}{}
```

Comment: Thx. It works for single, but not multiple references like`\autocite{ref1, ref2}` where a space and separator is missing in between.

Comment: For me this also worked with `\autocite{ref1, ref2}`. This problem might be fixed by now.

Comment: @Guido Could you also help to comment how to have `Author+Year+Title` instead of `Author+Title+Year` ? Many thanks !

Comment: For `Author+Title+Year`, you can use `citestyle=authoryear` and then change the macro to `\printfield{title}`.